# Error in comparing strings

Tags: vb.net, string

I have a string called `str` and in my event it is equal to "Administrator" when I use the code:

```
Dim AdminSTR As String = "Administrator"
    If str.ToString = AdminSTR Then
        Home.CurrentUser.Text = "Current User: " & UsernameTextBox.Text
        Home.CurrentUserSTR = UsernameTextBox.Text
        Home.AccessLBL.Text = " | Level: " & str
        Home.Show()
    Else
        ClientForm.Show()
    End If
```

It directs me to me `ClientForm`. While it should direct me to my `Home` form. Why is this so?

Thanks

Comment: If `str` is a `string` why do you use `ToString` to convert it to a `string`?

Comment: I was just making a quick check. It over rides anyway so makes no difference.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have any whitespace at begin/end of the `str`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just guessing, maybe it's "administrator" instead, .NET is case-sensitive by default. Or you have white-spaces at the beginning/end:

```
If "Administrator".Equals(str.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
    Home.CurrentUser.Text = "Current User: " & UsernameTextBox.Text
    Home.CurrentUserSTR = UsernameTextBox.Text
    Home.AccessLBL.Text = " | Level: " & str
    Home.Show()
Else
    ClientForm.Show()
End If
```

Comment: @Kraxed: Use the debugger and inspect the value of `str` at this point. Just set a breakpoint at the first line and use F10 + Quck-Watch-Window.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Compare()`

```
If String.Compare(str, AdminSTR) = 0 Then
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! I had a line of code which added a " " to the start of it to prevent it from being an empty value. Thanks to all that helped! Especially @TimSchmelter, for pointing out the cases and white-spaces! Voted up! :)

Comment: Use `Compare()` or `Equals()` (like Tim) but don't use `=` to compare `String`s.

Comment: If Tim's answer was the most helpful, then you should mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @Ravi - why not use = to compare strings other than if you need a case insensitive comparison?  Can you explain the reason for your statement?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway `=` equals only does a reference comparison so two different `String` objects with the same text content would fail the comparison. `Equals()` is faster as well (only by a small margin though).

Comment: @Ravi - When I look at the string class, the = operator is overloaded with this code:  `Return String.Equals(a, b)` so I see no reason not to use =.  It it more readable as well.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: +1 You're right. What I said doesn't hold true for VB.net. Thanks for the correction.